# Migrate from Google Data (GData) APIs to new Google APIs Client Library for Java

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-admin-sdk, google-provisioning-api, google-email-settings-api, google-profiles-api

In our organization we have an in-house developed web based application that make use of Google Data (GData) APIs(gdata-java-client) API to manage email user accounts, email settings, nickname, profile updates , contact management. This application was built some years back. Recently we planned to enhance some features and had a look at the API and Google API website. Looks like some of the GData APIs are getting deprecated or planning to take down(April 20, 2015). We are using below GData APIs and want to confirm/check which all APIs we need to migrate immediately to new Google APIs Client Library for Java (google-api-java-client) so that the services can function smoothly.

1) Google Apps Provisioning API - V2 (URL used - https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/{ourdomain}/user/2.0)
    For Creating User/Update User/Delete User/Nick Name

2) Google Apps Email Settings API - V2 (URL used -https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/{ourdomain}/{username}/webclip)
    For Disabling WebClip

3) Google Apps Profiles Data API - (URL Used - {hostname}/m8/feeds/profiles/domain/{ourdomain}/full/{username})
    For Retriving and Updating Profile

4) Google Domain Shared Contacts API - (URL Used - {hostname}/m8/feeds/contacts/{ourdomain}/full)
    For CreateContact/DeleteContact / UpdateContact

Jars/Versions of GData Libs that we are using today.
gdata-client-1.0.jar : 1.46.0 / gdata-core-1.0.jar : 1.46.0 / gdata-appsforyourdomain-1.0.jar : 1.3.1 /gdata-contacts-3.0.jar : 3.1.0

Please let us know what all APIs will be taken out of service on April 20,2015 and also please provide the new APIs that we can use for coding the migration. Do we also have any migration guide ? Can we keep gdata-java-client jars and google-api-java-client jars together in the class-path. We would like to migrate the services which are going to brought down by April 20, 2015.

Comment: Here is the link to check the API'S that going to be deprecated soon http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2014/12/reminder-to-migrate-to-updated-google.html

Comment: Thanks SGC. I had looked at the link and looks like only Google Apps Profiles and Provisioning API we need to re-mediate now. For Google Apps Profile can you please help in pointing to the new API. I could not find the corresponding API under ADMIN SDK.                         Also looks like Provisioning API is changed in ADMIN SDK, that means we need to rewrite the code as the packages, classes are changed. Is that a correct understanding ?   And for Contacts and Email Settings can be continue using GData jars ?

Comment: Adding one more question : When we migrate to new API do we need to make any changes to the Admin Account from Admin Console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had completed the migration and thought will update the thread and it might help someone else. Below APIs/components are getting shutdown by April 20, 2015.

1) Google Apps Provisioning API  Migrated to  ADMIN Directory API

2) Google Apps Profiles Data API  --> Migrated to --> ADMIN Directory API

3) ClientLogin --> Migrated to --> OAuth 2.0

Google Apps Email Settings API  is still under GDATA API but its placed under ADMIN SDK. No need to migrate this. But we were using ClientLogin Auth model so we need to move to OAuth 2.0

Also for using ADMIN SDK you need to make changes in Google Developer console and Admin console. Details in below links.
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation